# Why is there a pause before the light comes on/mac starts charging when plugging in?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

My mental model of a charger is that you plug it in and electricity fires out of it like a hose whether you like it or not. When I plug in my macbook charger, it often takes a few seconds before the light comes on and the menu bar icon says charging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical process of charging a battery:

First the system detects the power plug.

Now the Battery status is evaluated and and the battery circuit determines the amount of current to draw.

It is not like a hose, it is a calculated current amount. In other words the battery is the boss and only takes what it needs without overheating or damage.

If you look at you battery Icon in the menu bar you will see it takes a moment or two to determine how long it will take to charge to 100%.

Once that process is completed and the charging is on the way, you are given a visual indication (LED) of activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is only educated speculation, but I imagine it's related to the amount of switching that has to take place when changing from battery power to being on the mains. The electrical input needs to be registered, the hardware switched from running off battery to a charging state if needed, and time for the kernel to be informed of the state change based on the polling frequency. Then the other power management daemons have to pick up the state change and the OS get the message that the power state has changed. If that polling was taking place at intervals of less than a few seconds, I'd be surprised.